# Help with a table of variations (calculus)

Tags: tables, tkz-tab

I have passed the whole afternoon but still I cannot figure out a solution to this apparently easy problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[espcl=1.8]{$t$ /2,$x'(t)$ /2,$x(t)$ /2,$y'(t)$ /2,$y(t)$ /2} {$-\infty$, $1$,$\sqrt{3}$,$+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{0,+,d, +, ,  +,}
\tkzTabVar{-/$1$, +D-/$+\infty$/$-\infty$/, +/$-\frac{1}{2}$, +/$+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{0,+,d, +, z ,  -,}
\tkzTabVar{-/$1$, +D-/$+\infty$/$-\infty$/, +/$\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$, -/$-\infty$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition, any suggestions in order to have a better looking variation table are greatly apprciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674024/build-variation-table?rq=1 help?

Comment: @cfr Merci! I posted it already an answer to my own question thanks to your comment. The solution was tricky (use of `R/`).

Comment: Croeso! By the way, it is worth checking the links which come up on the right after you post the question. That's where I found it. The results there are often much better than you get from searching before posting. No idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @cfr and its useful citation I found the solution.
The following link is of valuable aid : https://www.sqlpac.com/en/documents/latex-tkz-tab-package-tikz-tables-of-signs-and-variations.html

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[lgt=1.20, espcl=2.5]{$t$ /1,$x'(t)$ /2,$x(t)$ /2,$y'(t)$ /2,$y(t)$ /2} {$-\infty$, $1$,$\sqrt{3}$,$+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{0,+,d, +, ,  +,}
\tkzTabVar{-/$1$, +D-/$+\infty$/$-\infty$/, R/, +/$+\infty$}
\tkzTabIma{2}{4}{3}{$\frac{1}{2}$}
   \tkzTabLine{0,+,d, +, z ,  -,}
\tkzTabVar{-/$0$, +D-/$+\infty$/$-\infty$/, +/$\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$, -/$-\infty$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]